# Nuxt js , не получается убрать слеши в конце url

Tags: vue.js, seo, redirect, nuxt.js

Столкнулся с проблемой слешей в конце урл. При внутренних переходах по сайту слешей в конце адреса нет, но если попробовать обновить страницу или зайти по ссылке, то в конце появится слеш.
Канонические ссылки прописал без слешей. Пробовал traillingSlash ставить false, но тогда страницы выдают 404 ошибку. Помогите люди знающие

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688604/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-from-url-in-nuxt-js/60621932#60621932

Comment: @Дмытрык redirect-module не работает при статичном хостинге сайта через run generate. Решил проблему с помощью правил в .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

При статичном хостинге сайта redirect-module не работает, поэтому пришлось решать проблему другими способами. Мне помогло решение с помощью файла .htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index.html [L]
```